# How to use multiple IEventAggregator for a Single Window in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a ShellWindow which has a IEventAggregator and all my child publish to this IEventAggregator?.

Now i have a static class named JIMSMessage in which i publish to IEventAggregator of ShellViewModel.

```
public static class JIMSMessage
{
    public static bool Show(IEventAggregator _events, string message)
    {
        _events.Publish(new Message()
        {
            MessageValue = message
        });

        return true;
    }        
}
```

I want my return value of Show method to come from the ViewModel, which calls this method..

Lets say...

I have a ViewModel named LedgerViewModel, this calls the JIMSMessage.Show as follows,

```
JIMSMessage.Show(_events,"Enter Ledger Name.");
```

Its working, but my MessageWindowViewModel returns something, which i want to return to JIMSMessage class, how can i do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `EventAggregator` is really meant to work that way. It is used to Publish events for anyone who cares to receive those events, or to Subscribe to events if something is interested in being alerted about an event.

It is not meant to be used to make a call and wait for a return value within the same method.

What you could do instead is publish something like a `ShowMessage` event, and subscribe to receive a `MessageShown` event.

For example, your `ShellViewModel` might subscribe to receive MessageDisplayed event messages and handle them like this:

```
public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
    // Subscribe to MessageDisplayed events
    events.GetEvent<MessageDisplayedEvent>().Subscribe(HandleMessageDisplayed);
}

void HandleMessageDisplayed(MessageDisplayedEvent e)
{
    if (e.SomeBooleanProperty)
        // Do Work
}
```

and elsewhere in your application you could publish a ShowMessage event to display a message

```
// Broadcast an Event
_events.GetEvent<ShowMessageEvent>().Publish(
    new ShowMessageEvent{ Message = "Enter Ledger Name." });
```

And whatever class is responsible for displaying messages would subscribe to receive `ShowMessageEvent`, show the message, wait for user feedback, then broadcast a `MessageDisplayed` event with the results when its finished.

Also if you're interested, I wrote [a Static class for the EventAggregator](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/) that makes dealing with PRISM's `EventAggregator` much simpler. You might be interested in checking it out.

Comment: But i am using caliburn micro

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Sorry, I'm not familiar with that framework and wasn't aware that they had a class called `EventAggregator` as well. My answer is still the same though: the `EventAggregator` is meant to be a decoupled messaging system, and I don't believe it was meant to do things like make calls and wait for a return value.